# Why doesn't printf work in multi-threaded program?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I have a multi-threaded program and cannot figure out why the printf does not work as expected.

This is my code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void *Msg(void *arg)
{
        pthread_t x;
        x= pthread_self();
        printf("x=%ld\n", x);
        printf("This MSG from a thread \n");
        pthread_exit((void*)0);
}



int main()
{
    pthread_t n;
    pthread_create(&n, NULL, Msg, NULL);
    pthread_create(&n, NULL, Msg, NULL);
    printf("Mother thread\n");
        return 0;
}
```

My question is why it doesn't printf the sentence "This MSG...".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should join the threads to **give them a chance to run** before the main thread exits. When one thread exits the process all the other threads are killed.

Try:

```
pthread_join(n, NULL);
return 0;
```

Comment: @Yucoat: Welcome to StackOverflow! If this posting answers your question, please mark it as 'Accepted' by clicking the checkmark icon.

Comment: Sorry,but i can't find this icon.

Comment: It's on the left of the answer, just below the down-arrow. On my screen it would be a quarter-inch left of `return 0;`

Comment: That's actually a bit misleading. All POSIX threads have equal status. As far as the process structure is concerned, the process will continue to live as long as at least one thread is running. The original thread ending by itself will not make all other threads to stop. The reason there's nothing printed in this case is either: 1) the original thread *intentionally* and *explicitly* killing the whole process in the prologue code, or 2) the original thread de-initializing input-output library in the prologue code (e.g. closing the `stdout`), which blocks output from other threads.